# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found - no build.gradle file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-import

i have imported an Android Studio project, into Android Studio yet the error appears:

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v2bF.png)

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

It appears on import that the Build.gradle file for the project and the settings.gradle file were not created

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtKjS.png)

this is log file :

```
2017-01-05 15:07:25,745 [ 381987]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'app' failed: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2017-01-05 15:07:25,755 [ 381997]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'app' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2017-01-05 15:07:25,795 [ 382037]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-01-05 15:07:25,797 [ 382039]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-01-05 15:07:25,798 [ 382040]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2017-01-05 15:07:25,799 [ 382041]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

Comment: There should be two `build.gradle` files. One at project level and other one at module level. The one you have is of the module level. You are missing the project level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @PrerakSola yes this is the problem , is there anyway to add it ?

Answer (score 3):

Create new file called `build.gradle` in the folder that contains your `app` folder. Paste the following content into it:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

So the structure would be:

```
Project Name
  - app
      - src
      - build
      - build.gradle
  - build
  - gradle
  - build.gradle (add this file)
```

Comment: can you tell me where i can find the option to add new build.gradle file ? and thank you so much

Comment: Just create a new file from the file browser and restart Android Studio.

Comment: You created it at a wrong place. Create it outside your `app` folder. The `app` folder and your new file should be in the same folder.

Comment: like that ? they told me that it's already exist : http://i.imgur.com/1XTUX7X.png

Comment: No @Bahae-EddineBenlamrabet, as Prerak Sola told you before, you're trying to create that in the wrong place. Look your last image, you're inside your app project folder. You need to create another build.gradle (or update the existant if there's one) on your root project folder.

Comment: @Bahae-EddineBenlamrabet You are missing a folder. 1. Create a folder with your project name (E.g. Hello World).  2. Copy your existing `app` folder inside it.  3. Create the new file inside `Hello world` folder.

Comment: i think you mean like that : http://i.imgur.com/Sl0yZ3y.png !!
( btw thank you all for helping )

Comment: @PrerakSola thank you so much i really appreciate your help , but the problem now is i can't run my app !! sorry for disturbing

Comment: It might be due to the name of your project. Change it to something else than `app`. After that, restart Android Studio.