# Gradle build error 1,0

Tags: android

I have tried to solve this problem by using previous posts on this forum and none of them worked. Can someone show me exactly what the problem is and how to solve it for this gradle?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.demo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Remove this block.
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://google.bintray.com/tensorflow'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error: (1,0)=: plugin with id com.android.application not found

Posts i have already tried: [Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found - no build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488653/error1-0-plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found-no-build-gradl)

Comment: can u show the other build.gradle file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a buildscript section like below.
You need to define where to download the android plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {

    /**
     * The repositories block configures the repositories Gradle uses to
     * search or download the dependencies. Gradle pre-configures support for remote
     * repositories such as JCenter, Maven Central, and Ivy. You can also use local
     * repositories or define your own remote repositories. The code below defines
     * JCenter as the repository Gradle should use to look for its dependencies.
     *
     * New projects created using Android Studio 3.0 and higher also include
     * Google's Maven repository.
     */

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    /**
     * The dependencies block configures the dependencies Gradle needs to use
     * to build your project. The following line adds Android plugin for Gradle
     * version 3.1.0 as a classpath dependency.
     */

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.demo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Remove this block.
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```